# Resolve relative image links in SCSS from node_modules with Webpack in Rails 6

Tags: webpack, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to incorporate [MediaElement.js](https://www.mediaelementjs.com) in a Rails 6 app, and I'm trying to do it what seems to be "the right way" for Rails 6, i.e., installing the module with `yarn` and managing it with Webpacker.

In plain HTML, using a CDN, I would just put the following in my `<head>` tag:

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediaelement@4.2.10/build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediaelement@4.2.10/build/mediaelementplayer.css">
```

Attempting to translate this into WebPacker, I added this line to `/app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```js
require("mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min")
```

and this line to `/app/javascript/packs/application.scss`:

```css
@import '~mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer';
```

When I hit the page, however, `application.self-[…].css` doesn't include the mediaelementplayer CSS, and the JavaScript console shows:

```
application.scss:4 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './mejs-controls.svg'
    at webpackMissingModule (application.scss:4)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./app/javascript/packs/application.scss (application.scss:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../app/javascript/packs/application.scss (application.scss?86ad:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

The file it's looking for does exist, in `node_modules/mediaelement/build/mejs-controls.svg`.

How can I get Webpack / Webpacker to resolve these relative resources correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue as you. The css you're importing is being loaded into the same directory as `/app/javascript/packs/application.scss` so when it looks for `mejs-controls.svg` it's looking in the same directory of your rails app and not finding it.

You need to copy the svg file from `node_modules/mediaelement/build/mejs-controls.svg` and put it in the same directory as your `application.scss`. Doing this solved it for me.